# Trying to set up a range filter for related custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, query-posts

I have set up two CPTs, "Property" and "Suite".

Each Property has a number of Suites assigned to it via an ACF bidirectional relationship.  Each suite has a set size (in square feet).   What I'd like to do is set up a filter (which I've done on this page: https://worthsastage.wpengine.com/our-listings) that a user can use the range slider to adjust for the size of the suite they would like, but instead of having the suites listed in the results (like it currently is), I'd like to have the Property that the suite belongs to listed. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: note that ACF questions and other questions about working with 3rd party plugins are off-topic here. You could try and display all the results, include the number of suites in the HTML as a data attribute, and use the range control as a javascript based filter, but if you want to do this server side then you'll need to ask this question in an ACF community or via their official support routes as it can't be answered without ACF knowledge and ACF specialised expertise

Comment: Hi Tom, Thanks for the suggestion.  My apologies, I was mainly focused on the filter part of my issue.  I will move this to a more appropriate forum.